# Checkbox on CardView with MultiChoiceModeListener?

Tags: java, android, xml, adapter, cardview

I'm creating a notes app and I have all my notes shown in a cardview on my MainActivity. I have a MultiChoiceModeListener that I'm using for deleting multiple notes at once. I've succeeded in getting functionality to the contextual actionbar to where I can select notes and delete all selected notes. the problem I haven't been able to solve however is when an item is selected there's no checkbox, no highlighted selector, nothing. I have nothing showing the item is selected other than me knowing which item I selected and the count of items in the array.

What I have tried so far

- adding Checkbox to item_note and setting to visible+checked in CAB when itemstatechanged, which resulted in a crash (I can only change item_note from the adapter)
- I've also tried using the listSelector which wasn't very successful as I'm using a cardview and the listSelector only affected the background behind cardview

Here's my code

ContextualActionBar

```
mListViewNotes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_notes);
    mListViewNotes.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    mListViewNotes.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView);

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

            String cab_no_note_count = getResources().getString(R.string.cab_no_notes_count);

            if (list_items.contains(notes.get(position))) {
                count = count-1;
                list_items.remove(notes.get(position));
                if (getThemeCountInt() == 0) {
                    String cab_note_count = getResources().getString(R.string.cab_notes_count, count);
                    mode.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(cab_note_count));
                } else if (getThemeCountInt() == 1){
                    mode.setTitle(count + " Notes Selected");
                }
            } else {
                count = count+1;
                list_items.add(notes.get(position));
                if (getThemeCountInt() == 0) {
                    String cab_note_count = getResources().getString(R.string.cab_notes_count, count);
                    mode.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(cab_note_count));
                } else if (getThemeCountInt() == 1){
                    mode.setTitle(count + " Notes Selected");
                }
            }

            if (count == 0) {
                if (getThemeCountInt() == 0) {
                    mode.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(cab_no_note_count));
                } else if (getThemeCountInt() == 1){
                    mode.setTitle("No Notes Selected");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
            actionMode = mode;
            action = true;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            deleteNote();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            count = 0;
            app_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            list_items.clear();
        }
    });
```

NoteAdapter

```
public class NoteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Note>{

Context ctx;
MainActivity mainActivity;
public static CheckBox checkBox;

public NoteAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Note> notes) {
    super(context, resource, notes);

    this.ctx = context;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);



    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_note, null);
    }


    mainActivity = (MainActivity) ctx;
    Note note = getItem(position);

    if(note != null) {
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_note_title);
        TextView content = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_note_content);
        TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_note_date);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxTest);



        Typeface music_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/melodymakernotesonly.ttf");
        Typeface scribble_card = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/the unseen.ttf");

        if (getThemeCountInt() == 0) {
            title.setTypeface(music_font);
        } else if (getThemeCountInt() == 1) {
            title.setTypeface(scribble_card);
        }

        content.setTypeface(scribble_card);

        title.setText(note.getTitle());
        date.setText(note.getDateTimeFormatted(getContext()));

        if(note.getContent().length() > 25) {
            content.setText(note.getContent().substring(0,25) + "...");
        } else {
            content.setText(note.getContent());
        }

        if(note.getContent().length() <= 0) {
            content.setText("(Empty Note..)");
        } else {
            content.setText(note.getContent());
        }

        if (note.getTitle().length() <= 0) {
            title.setText("(Untitled)");
        } else {
            title.setText(note.getTitle());
        }

    }

    return convertView;
}

private int getThemeCountInt() {
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("theme", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int selectedTheme = mSharedPreferences.getInt("theme", 0);
    return selectedTheme;

}
```

item_note

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/item_note">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="6dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewBackground"
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:theme="?attr/customCardBackground" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clef_note"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/treble_clef"
        app:theme="?attr/musicThemeRemove" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxTest"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:buttonTint="@color/red"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        app:theme="?attr/notebookRedLine"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="780dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        style="?attr/musicThemeLines"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="780dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        style="?attr/musicThemeLines"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="780dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
        style="?attr/musicThemeLines" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scaleType="center">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_note_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            style="?attr/item_note_title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_note_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="@color/gunmetal"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
            style="?attr/item_note_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:theme="?attr/lastUpdatedDate">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:text="Last Updated:"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_note_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I just figured something out but its not 100% working yet, any insight would be great

```
if (mainActivity.list_items.contains(note)) {
            checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else if (!mainActivity.list_items.contains(note)) {
            checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }
```

I've added this to my NoteAdapter and it seems to be doing something right. With this, my first selected item shows a check when its selected and removes it when it's not. but only my first selected item is showing this change. anything I select after doesn't show a checkbox :/ I'm not sure what's causing this as I know when I select other items they are contained in mainActivity.list_items just like my first note is

Comment: why dont you set the alpha of cardview (or the background as light grey) whenever you select the card

Comment: i guess that would be an option but i wanted to try to keep my background for my CardView :/ i was thinking more of a checkbox. I've updated my question with something i figured out. i think I'm on the right track i just can't figure out where i'm going wrong